# Disable generating post single URL or prevent from crawl

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Suppose, I have a post category called `XYZ`. I already posted 3 different posts to this category.

These are as follows

```
1st posts - www.example.com/2015/04/20/1st-posts/
2nd posts - www.example.com/2015/04/20/2nd-posts/
3rd posts - www.example.com/2015/04/20/3rd-posts/
```

I already showing them in a page called `MNO` and the titles are not linkable. So, users can't see the single view of the posts. That's fine. But, I can view them as a single posts by opening these URLs in browsers and search engines also crawling these posts URLs. For search engines, people are coming to these pages although these posts title are not clickable on the `MNO` page.

Now, My question is -

1. Can I prevent crawling? Or,
2. Can I remove these URLs and post content will be available for `MNO` page too?
3. Which will be the best way to do? `.htaccess` or any other way?

N.B. Actually, I can't move to any custom post types or own created plugin. Because, there are at least 5000 posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent a web crawler from crawling anything that's publicly visible, but you can ask politely for crawlers not to index certain pages. Read up on [robots file](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

Comment: Okay. Nice! I will say politely. :) But, for 5000+ pages... one by one or there are some other way to do.

Comment: @SamratKhan have a look at the link I posted. You can disallow an entire directory from your site so you don't have to create it one file at a time. PS, welcome to stackoverflow, you'll get your first 2 points when you hit the check mark to the right of my answer.